# Программно выделить строку в ListBox

Tags: c, winapi

Пытаюсь выделить строку. Имеется такой listbox. Выделяю следующим образом:

```
int a = SendMessage(hwnd, LB_SELITEMRANGE, (WPARAM)(BOOL)TRUE, MAKELPARAM(2, 0));
```

В переменной a всегда -1. Почему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.: listbox чужой программы. HWND листа я получил, проверил, послав сообщение "выделена ли строка". В этом случаем SendMessage возвращаем все верно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена следующим образом:

```
SendMessage(hwnd, LB_SETCURSEL, (WPARAM)2, NULL);
```

Нужная строка выделяется как надо.